# Failed to install rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

As title

git:(master) ✗ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rails-5.1.4/README.md

git:(master) ✗ sudo gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-5.1.4
Parsing documentation for rails-5.1.4
Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed

~ git:(master) ✗ rails -v
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
```

You can then rerun your "rails" command.

Comment: did you run `sudo gem install rails`? what OS ?

Comment: my os is OSX
yes,  after sudo gem install rails >>>Successfully installed rails-5.1.4 Parsing documentation for rails-5.1.4 Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds 1 gem installed
but if i check the version of rails it shows Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

$ sudo gem install rails
You can then rerun your "rails" command.

Comment: my os is OSX
yes,  after sudo gem install rails >>>Successfully installed rails-5.1.4 Parsing documentation for rails-5.1.4 Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds 1 gem installed
but if i check the version of rails it shows Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

$ sudo gem install rails
You can then rerun your "rails" command.

Comment: What Ruby version are you using if you are using a ruby version manager?

Comment: ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16]

Comment: @曾濟彬 I faced the same issue, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use:

1. `rbenv` for ruby installation
2. and only with it use `gem install rails`

Usually installing gems with `sudo` is a bad idea, that brings a lot of problems with permissions.

Comment: so I should remove my ruby and do it all over again?

Comment: no, just install rbenv, it will override system-wide ruby

Comment: ~ git:(master) ✗ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rails-5.1.4/README.md

Comment: Can't solve the problem...I have installed ruby by rbenv

Comment: It looks like you have some troubles with rbenv installation. You are still using system version of ruby.